# How to store two different cache "tables" in Redis under the same database/index?

Tags: caching, redis, nosql

Trying to build a data set of two cache tables (which are currently stored in SQL Server) - one is the actual cache table (CacheTBL); the other is the staging table (CacheTBL_Staging).

The table structure has two columns - "key", "value"

So I'm wondering how to implement this in Redis as I'm a total noob to this NoSQL stuff.  Should I use a SET or LIST?  Or something else?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide whether you want separate REDIS keys for all entries using SET and GET, or put them into hashes with HSET and HGET. If you use the first approach, your keys should include a prefix to distinguish between main and staging. If you use hashes, this is not necessary, because the hash name can also be used to distinguish these. You probably also need to decide how you want to check for cache validity, and what your cache flushing strategy should be. This normally requires some additional data structures in REDIS.

Comment: So if I were to use HSET & HGET, it would look something like this:

HSET myCacheHash key1 value1
HSET myCacheHash_Staging key2 value2

where the myCacheHash & myCacheHash_Staging are kinda like the sql server table names - CacheTBL & CacheTBL_Staging?

Comment: Yes that's the idea. You should probably experiment with other options, too. For example, you could store a hash for each key, containing sub-keys "main" and "staging", if that fits you usage.

Comment: Thank you @Hans-Martin!!